# Java8 Create Map grouping by key contained in values

Tags: collections, java-8, hashmap

I have the following two lists of String:

```
{APPLE, ORANGE, BANANA} //call it keyList
{APPLE123, ORANGEXXX, 1APPLE, APPLEEEE} //call it valueList
```

Desired output is an `HashMap<String, List<String>>` like this:

```
<APPLE, {APPLE123, 1APPLE, APPLEEEE}>
<ORANGE, {ORANGEXXX}>
<BANANA, {}> //also <key, null> is accepted
```

I have implemented this solution(it works)

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
keyList.forEach(key -> {
    List<String> values = valueList.stream()
            .filter(value -> value.contains(key))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    myMap.put(key, values);
});
```

Given the assumption that a value is related to only one key (it's a constraint of my domain), is this the best solution in java8 , in terms of performance and/or code cleaning ?
Can it be tuned in some way?

Answer (score 1):

If you can safely assume that each value is associated with a key, and only one key, you can go into the following direction:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(String.join("|", keyList));
Map<String, List<String>> map = valueList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        if(!m.find()) throw new AssertionError();
        return m.group();
    }));

map.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println(k+": "+v));
```

If the keys may contain special characters which could get misinterpreted as regex constructs, you can change the preparation code to

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
    keyList.stream().map(Pattern::quote).collect(Collectors.joining("|")));
```

The `collect` operation does only create the groups for existing values. If you really need all keys to be present, you can use

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = valueList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> {
            Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
            if(!m.find()) throw new AssertionError();
            return m.group();
        },
        HashMap::new, // ensure mutable map
        Collectors.toList()
    ));
keyList.forEach(key -> map.putIfAbsent(key, Collections.emptyList()));
```

or

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
    keyList.stream().map(Pattern::quote)
           .collect(Collectors.joining("|", ".*(", ").*")));
Map<String, List<String>> map = valueList.stream()
    .map(p::matcher)
    .filter(Matcher::matches)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(m -> m.group(1),
        HashMap::new, // ensure mutable map
        Collectors.mapping(Matcher::group, Collectors.toList())
    ));
keyList.forEach(key -> map.putIfAbsent(key, Collections.emptyList()));
```

Comment: thank you very much for your detailed examples. I will try the last two options. 
As far as I understand, your solutions  avoid to loop the valueList for each key (maybe it does it under the wood, but in an efficient way).

Comment: Keep in mind that `String.contains` bears an internal loop too. So you basically have `for each value(for each key(for each character(…)))` in your original code, whereas only the innermost loop can stop at a match. So you have at least `number of keys × number of values` operations. My solution basically does `for each value(for each character(for each key(…)))` which can stop the “for each character” at the first match, which is more efficient when we know that there will always be a match. Further, as you suspected, the innermost loop as done by the regex engine is more efficient too.